# Django Context processors missing while they are in the settings

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-1.8, django-context

This is what i get in my terminal when i start the server locally:

```
Required context processor django_facebook.context_processors.facebook wasnt found
Required context processor django.core.context_processors.request wasnt found
/Users/iam-tony/.envs/party_project/lib/python3.4/importlib/_bootstrap.py:321: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The django.forms.util module has been renamed. Use django.forms.utils instead.
  return f(*args, **kwds)
```

But Here are my settings and both context_processors are there:

```
    TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-BACKEND
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs
        'DIRS': [
            str(APPS_DIR.path('templates')),
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-debug
            'debug': DEBUG,
            # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-loaders
            # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#loader-types
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ],
            # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                # Your stuff: custom template context processors go here
                #django_facebook context procesor:
                'django_facebook.context_processors.facebook',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I am using cookiecutter and Django1.8. I've been on this for a few days now but I can't seem to find a similar post about it.

Comment: Have you installed `django_facebook`?

Comment: @sobolevn yes i have!

Comment: Do you have multiple settings files? Did you overwrite your context processors in a different place?

Comment: @jeffabiny Django version 1.8.5, using settings 'config.settings.local'. There are no context processors in local. only in the common file where everything gets imported from.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [django-facebook code](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook/blob/60003f62d79dfbe6f910d39d0b3cbe70de3c2462/django_facebook/models.py#L54), it is out of date

```
# make sure the context processors are present
required = ['django_facebook.context_processors.facebook',
            'django.core.context_processors.request']
context_processors = settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS
for context_processor in required:
    if context_processor not in context_processors:
        logger.warn(
            'Required context processor %s wasnt found', context_processor)
```

It's checking the old setting, `setting.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` which was used for Django < 1.8, instead of the new `context_processors` option.

There's [an issue](https://github.com/tschellenbach/Django-facebook/issues/542) on the projects GitHub repository about this. Until it is fixed, it's only a warning, so you are safe to ignore it.

Comment: It is but when I am using it I get the debug page saying that it need the context processor.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the debug page? You might want to reconsider whether you want to rely on a project that doesn't support Django 1.8, six months after it has been released. If django-facebook doesn't work with Django 1.8, then Stack Overflow can't help you.